# jQuery bind method

Tags: jquery, html

In one of my HTML page dynamically loading some file field while clicking a button like follows

```
$('#add').click(function(){


$('#files').append('<input type="file" class="myfile" name="myfile" />');


});
```

My question is how to "bind" newly added element to HTML page so that I can access like

```
$('.myfile').change(function(){
// Code Here
});
```

I am asking this because

```
$('.myfile').live('change',function(){
// Code here
});
```

not working in all browsers , expecially IE

Please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) when you are using jQuery 1.7+ or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if lower.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on

P.S. What version of IE are we talking about, because `.live()` should work (although slow as shit).

**UPDATE**

Demo for`.delegate()`: http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/zqbBX/
Demo for `.on()`: http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/ddJrs/

Answer (score 1):

try onchange event while using IE

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `.on()`. `.live()` is deprecated.

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '.myfile', function(){
       alert("it works!");
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#add').click(function(){
  var item = $('<input type="file" class="myfile" name="myfile" />').change(function(){
    alert('TEST');
  });
  $('#files').append(item);
});
```